# Performance: Overloaded [] and a call to a function

Tags: c++

My initial thought over the performance of calling an over loaded [] to acquire a member data and calling a function like getData(index) would be the same.  Since calling [] is essentially a function call.  Assume they acquire the same data like values[1] and values.getData(1) would return the same value. Am I wrong?  If they perform the same, is there a non-performance advantage to using [] in this case?

Comment: Yes, it's more readable. That's the advantage. Even if there was a performance difference, you'd have to profile it before worrying.

Comment: I personally find that using operator overloading (such as []) makes the code less readable as it is less transparent to what is actually happening. Many people much more experienced than I think operator overloading is a bad idea - read the (sometimes hilarious) C++ FQA if you dare: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/operator.html

Comment: I can live with using any or both.  I just wanted to be sure that there is no performance difference (in the mentioned case above).  It's just that there are people who think it's more efficient (performance wise) just because they see the use of [].  The class in question was for a Vector3D.  Someone overloaded [] to access x, y, z.

Comment: @WayneUroda: I have read through the C++ FQA before, and the writer demonstrate that he is **not** really experienced in C++. Other than that, you are right in that there are experts that go either way, and in my personal opinion is more a question of the particular design: does it make sense for this particular type? If you are implementing `std::vector` or `std::array`, it makes sense, and it allows the use of your container in generic code that expects that operator... but in many cases operators are abused.

Comment: @WayneUroda, If you want to use `num.add(num.minus(3));`, go ahead. You still have just as little idea of what those functions actually do, and I find it a whole lot less readable than `num += num - 3;`. Functions can be abused just as much as operators.

Comment: @chris an example from my actual experience - in pre C++11, comparing two vectors can only be done with the == operator (please correct me if I'm wrong). As a result, the code `if (vector1 == vector2)` might not be as clear as `if (vector1.compare(vector2) == 0)` as at first glance it might look like I was comparing two pointers, rather than two objects. Of course it all comes down the particular types involved and personal preference - I just think if an overloaded operator is available, so should a method be available. Just my opinion!

Comment: As for the OP's situation, personally (don't lambast me please!) I would prefer to use `vector.x()` `vector.y()` and `vector.z()` methods. Anybody familiar with a vector in 3d space would immediately know what they do, whereas they might have to look inside the vector class to find out what `vector[1]` does. I agree though that being able to add two vectors like `result = vec1 + vec2` is extremely useful. So yes, it is about inappropriate use more than anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, under the hood. Overloaded operators are just a unique syntax for a function call. The only thing changing is the appearance of code that calls it.

You're even allowed to force the operator calls to look function-like.

```
values[1]
```

may also be written as

```
values.operator[]( 1 )
//     ^^^^^^^^^^ This is effectively the name of your function.
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same thing, as you also mention in your question. Overloads are just function calls. No performance gain.

However, `operator[]` historically means that (or is expected to have) there is a contiguous formation of internal data representation in the memory, or more generally serve as an index to container like data structures. Thus, it is generally implemented in classes like vectors, arrays, matrices, etc.

Comment: @Benjamin As I said, it is no constraint, it is just a general convention.

Comment: @meyumer: ... but it is not. Even in the standard library there are about as many containers implementing `operator[]` that have contiguous memory as there are that don't have contiguous memory. By convention `operator[]` is meant to represent *indexing*, regardless of the internal representation. In an array, `std::vector`, `std::array` the index is a position in a contiguous block. In `std::deque` it is still a position, although not contiguous, in `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` it is indexing by key...

Comment: Yes, indexing is more complete. Let me revise that.

Comment: @meyumer off topic, but by contagious I think you mean contiguous or continuous.  Just FYI for future usage.  I read your post pretty fast and actually thought you were saying it's contagious to use the square brackets. As a general rule, I'm only going to overload [] when indexing or fast access of random item in a contiguous data is required.  Thanks for all replies.